# Optimized session implementation in ASP.Net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

In the authentication controller I'm storing my login info into session["userinfo"], I want to  reuse this session in all my controllers , which is the best optimized way to do this

Comment: Session is the same for all the controllers. You can call session["userinfo"] in any other controller in your application. It is not clear what you are asking...

Comment: Why do you need `Session["userinfo"]` in all your controllers. Do you want to check if User Info Session is null or not for each controller?

Comment: In each and every API request I have to pass the userid and role , so I'm storing those values in the session as a model, and I'm using the same session in all my controllers to get user info before calling the API, In the internal code review our lead was saying that don't convert the session to model in all controller keep it in one common place , he was asking for code re usability

Comment: User.Identity.GetUserId(); RolePrincipal r = (RolePrincipal)User;
       rolesArray = r.GetRoles();

Comment: I will get the user info from my login API response, that response only I'm storing in the session